# I get the error "Unsupported Media Type Did not attempt to load JSON data(...)."

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I am using `python` and `flask`, and I am trying to make a web application for making flashcards.

However, when I try to submit my flashcards (i.e., when I fill out the fields "course", "lecture", "front" and "back", and press "Enter"), I get the error

> Unsupported Media Type Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'..

To my understanding, I am executing my JSON properly, but there seems to be a mistake somewhere. Can anyone help me or give recommendations? Any help is appreciated.

This is my `app.py`.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, flash, jsonify, make_response
import sqlite3
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set a secret key for the session cookie
app.secret_key = "secret"

# Connect to the database
conn = sqlite3.connect("flashcards.db")

db = conn.cursor()

# Create a table to store the flashcards
db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS flashcards (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, user TEXT, course TEXT, lecture INTEGER, front TEXT, back TEXT)")
conn.commit()

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def make():
    if request.method == "GET":
        user = request.cookies.get("user")

        if user:
            # Get the courses and lectures from the database using the db variable
            db.execute("SELECT DISTINCT course FROM flashcards WHERE user = ?", (user,))
            courses = db.fetchall()
            db.execute("SELECT DISTINCT lecture FROM flashcards WHERE user = ?", (user,))
            lectures = db.fetchall()
            # Pass the courses and lectures to the render_template function
            return render_template("make.html", courses=courses, lectures=lectures)
        else:
            # If there are no cookies, generate a random user name
            user = "user" + str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
            # Pass the user name to the render_template function
            return render_template("make.html", user=user)

    elif request.method == "POST":
        # Get the JSON data from the request
        data = request.get_json()
        # Get the user, course, lecture, front, and back values
        user = data["user"]
        course = data["course"]
        lecture = data["lecture"]
        front = data["front"]
        back = data["back"]
        # Check if the course already exists in the database, and if not, create a new one using the db variable
        db.execute("INSERT INTO courses (name) SELECT ? WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM courses WHERE name = ?)", (course, course))
        conn.commit()
        # Check if the lecture already exists in the database, and if not, create a new one using the db variable
        db.execute("INSERT INTO lectures (course, number) SELECT ?, ? WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM lectures WHERE course = ? AND number = ?)", (course, lecture, course, lecture))
        conn.commit()
        # Add the flashcard using the db variable
        db.execute("INSERT INTO flashcards (user, course, lecture, front, back) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (user, course, lecture, front, back))
        conn.commit()
        # Create a response object
        response = make_response(jsonify({"success": True}))
        # Set a cookie with the user value
        response.set_cookie("user", user)
        # Return the response object
        return response
```

And this is my "make.html"

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Make
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<h1>Make Flashcards</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <form id="flashcard-form" method="POST" action="/">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="course">Course</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="course" name="course" placeholder="Enter the course name" list="courselist" required>
          <datalist id="courselist">
            {% for course in courses %}
            <option value="{{ course }}">{{ course }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </datalist>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lecture">Lecture</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="lecture" name="lecture" placeholder="Enter the lecture number" list="lecturelist" required>
          <datalist id="lecturelist">
            {% for lecture in lectures %}
            <option value="{{ lecture }}">{{ lecture }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </datalist>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="front">Front</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="front" name="front" placeholder="Enter the question or term" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="back">Back</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="back" name="back" placeholder="Enter the answer or definition" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

<script>
  // Adding an event listener to the form which triggers when the user presses the enter key
  document.getElementById("flashcard-form").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    // Checking if the key being pressed is "Enter"
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      // Preventing the default form submission
      event.preventDefault();
      // Getting the front and back input values
      var front = document.getElementById("front").value;
      var back = document.getElementById("back").value;
      // Creating a data object to send to the server
      var data = {front: front, back: back};
      // Using fetch to send the data to the server
      fetch("/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        // Handling the response from the server
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        // If the data was successfully sent, show a message and clear the fields
        if (data.success) {
          alert("Flashcard created successfully!");
          document.getElementById("front").value = "";
          document.getElementById("back").value = "";
        } else {
          // If the submission failed, show an error message
          alert("Flashcard creation failed!");
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // Handle any errors
        console.error(error);
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

I tried checking my imports, and they seem all fine. I also tried asking Copilot and ChatGPT, but they also say that my code looks fine. For some reason, I seem to have issues when using the debugger of VScode.

Comment: Is this pythin issuing the error? by the way, you're only sending `front` and `back` in the request, no `course` or `lecture` - also, check the browser developer tools to see what you're actually sending, I suspect `preventDefault` on a `keydown` event won't prevent the form submit (I could be wrong though)

Comment: The error is being issued on the web browser when I submit the form. Thank you for the insight about course and lecture, I guess I overlooked that! Any ideas on what the JSON issue may be though?

Comment: so the error is a browser error, not an error in the response?